# Question about current emergence in primary and secondary of transformers

Tags: electric-current

[image]

Hello, I want to ask two cases about transformers, in the first case there is a resistance and AC source at primary and nothing at secondary, and in the second case, there is just an AC source at primary and nothing at secondary. Appearently, because voltage does not depend on resistance, there will be voltage difference at either sides in both cases.

For currents, I think that there will be current at primary in both cases because they are closed circuits, but in both cases even if there is an induced emf at secondary parts, because there is no  resistance at secondary parts, there will be no current at secondary parts. So I think that there will be current at primary in both cases, but no current at secondary in both cases, am I right?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Are you assuming that the wires have zero resistance (i.e., they're superconducting)?  The resistance of the wires themselves will be important, and the answer will be different if their resistance is really zero or just "very very small".

Comment: Hello, yes, assume that there is no resistance on windings and wires at all. I just realize that, there actually has to be current on the secondary in both cases as well because, as I said, because there is an AC generator in primary (so there is a varying voltage in primary), then there is also varying voltage on secondary and because of the inductive reactance (coming from secondary winding) on secondary, then there has to be current in secondary in both cases, am I right?